# Best way of having common code for both admin and front-end

Tags: development, joomla-3.4, custom-component

We are developing a component for joomla 3.x. In the component there are certain set of library functions (php files)  which are want to used in both the admin side and front-end.

At the moment we have these library functions inside the folder 'administrator/comonents/com_mycom/libraries' and importing these libraries in both admin and front. We feel this is not correct and want a common place to have these libraries.

What is the best place we can keep these libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use the library feature provided by Joomla. It is well documented here:

https://docs.joomla.org/Using_own_library_in_your_extensions

Your library folder will be stored in Joomla libraries folder, usually under `JPATH_ROOT.'/libraries'` (`JPATH_LIBRARIES`)